# address family not supported by protocol _only_ in Eclipse after disable/enable IPv6 on Network Adapters

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, ipv6

Hi and thanks for any help in advance:

I'm seeing this well known and discussed issue.  However, this is *only* when running/debugging in Eclipse, Juno on Win 7.  VM version matters not.

Therefore, this is an Eclipse-only issue.  This does not happen when I run the same app standalone - only within Eclipse (did I say that already ;-) )

This occurred after (for testing purposes) I disabled IPv6 on my network adapters and then enabled IPv6 on those same adapters.

The application is simple: creates a multicast server on the WS-Discovery port to listen and report on any UDP multicasts to that group.  This program works fine in all cases and platforms except on the machine and in Eclipse where I disabled/enabled IPv6 as described above.

Also:
1) Yes, PreferIPv6Addresses = true and PreferIPv4Stack = false
   - Args set in the code
2) No, the Win 7 host file is not messed up
3) No, this is not an Android app

Here is the error followed by the code.

Thanks again, in advance,

Tom

```
Protocol family not supported
java.net.SocketException: Protocol family not supported
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:368)
    at java.net.MulticastSocket.<init>(MulticastSocket.java:147)


System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "false");
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "true");

// bind to all IPv6 ports (in contrast to "0.0.0.0" for IPv4 binding)
InetAddress ia6BindTo = InetAddress.getByName("::");
SocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress(ia6BindTo, 3702);

// bam
MulticastSocket ms = new MulticastSocket(sa);

// no longer gets this far since disable/enable IPv6 on net adapters
InetAddress m_GroupAddress = InetAddress.getByName("[FF02::C]");
ms.joinGroup(m_GroupAddress);
```

Comment: Can you check that you are using the same version of JVM that you are using for running the application standalone?

Comment: Good question, thanks.  Yes, I did check and made sure that my .bat file pointed to the same Installed JVM I'm using within Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer "Why?".

This is the answer to a workaround.

I deleted the Installed JVM from Eclipse and reinstalled it.  Behavior cleared.

This isn't fully acceptable to me for two reasons:

1) The problem repeats when I disable/enable IPv6 again.  Therefore, the workaround must be repeated.
2) I must configure projects and run configurations further to make the desired JVM the default again.

If I find out why this is occuring in Eclipse, I will post my findings.